# Custom Mapbox tileset not showing in Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am making a game for a Bible camp, and am wanting to use Leaflet.js for the map. I am creating a style using Mapbox. I imported the coordinates of Rome and Jerusalem into Mapbox via a csv upload, and they render just fine in the [preview](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/wheelerj/cioerd0vf001yacm7rff4tj5h.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoid2hlZWxlcmoiLCJhIjoiY2lvZXJheTZrMDByNXVsbTNpZXp0c2VnbCJ9.T_jRdbo0CKUgZ2aiuA3kKA#3.97/37.38/14.73). However, they do not show on when loaded via Leaflet. See code below:

```
<head>
  <title>Race to Rome</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
</head>

<body>
 <div id="mapid" style="height:500px;"></div>
   <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<h1>Race to Rome</h1>


</body>

<script>

        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView(L.latLng(34,30), 5);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/wheelerj/cioerd0vf001yacm7rff4tj5h/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoid2hlZWxlcmoiLCJhIjoiY2lvZXJheTZrMDByNXVsbTNpZXp0c2VnbCJ9.T_jRdbo0CKUgZ2aiuA3kKA', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 
                'Imagery &copy;<a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(mymap);

</script>
```

What do I need to do in order to include these labels in Leaflet?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to look into using [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/) (which is an Leaflet fork enhanced for their users), and using their pre-built features for handing feature layers like this.
See example below.

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/show-marker-as-label/

```
L.mapbox.featureLayer('MY_FEATURE_LABEL_SET')
    .on('ready', function(e) {
        gj.addData(this.getGeoJSON());
    });
```

Comment: Got caught up on other things, but plan to return to it someday.